# File transfer works only with specified suffixes

Tags: bluetooth

No problems to transfer files with some extensions like `.jpg` via bluetooth.

But for files with majority of other suffixes (e. g. `.avi`, `.apk`) I have first rename them, then transfer them and finally on the target device rename it back:

```
name.apk ---> name.jpg ----- bluetooth transfer ----> name.jpg ---> name.apk
```

Is there any more simple way to do it?

(For example from Adroid 5.0 to Android 2.2.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no simple solution except run some third party application on your device that accepts any types of files.

Usually Bluetooth implementation on handheld devices limits receving file type to only supported. Such as 3gp, jpg and few others.

Also this days security is a problem so Android may also reject any APK or other risk file types.

So by other words: it is limited by device by security reason.

Comment: Which 3rd party application?

Comment: Any one that impl,ements ObjectPush or FileTransfer Profiles. For example this one: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.medieval.blueftp&hl=en_US

Comment: Thanks. I just want to state that this is not security in my view but just some kind of obfuscation and creating a bad experience for experienced users. A warning on the receiving side or the option to run a malware check seems more appropriate. Phishers will probably also tell people to rename it to `.txt` and back when copying and people will do it.

Answer (score 1):

Most Androids don't accept .apk file over bluetooth. This is to prevent people from sending malicious software to phones that are not protected.

If you still want to send APKs over Bluetooth, there are mainly 3 ways of doing so:

1. Change the extension (.APK) from your phone. This way you can trick the phone in still accepting the application.
2. You can zip the .apk file and send it over bluetooth and unzip it again at receivers end.
3. Another way is to use some third party app which allows you to directly transfer .apk file.

Comment: Which 3rd party application?

Comment: There are many such applications present in the market like **apk extractor** , **Apk Share Bluetooth** , etc. You can search on play store.